Androidstudio (built 22 november) ladybug macos intel edition missing javascript typescript plugin
Is it just me? I went to the official download page, downloaded the install image for macos, intel edition and installed android studio. Most things works great, including gemini. Well as good gemini can work at least. I wrote a simple ma application for android (dont ask), and discovered that i didnt get syntax highlighting in the editor on the javascript portions of the html file which defined the azure map component. So I went down the rabbit hole (settings--> plugins choose the installed tab and expected to fins the javascript and typescript plugin to be disabled. But i couldnt find it at all. After some searching i discovered that it wasnt in the plugin folder, and looking directly in the installation package as downloaded from the android studio website it wasnt present there either.
So what gives, is this a bug, or is it it simply ommited and the javascript support has been removed in ladybug? Or is this support moved somewhere elese or? As in a specific plugin which has to be gotten from the marketplace instead from the bundled plugins?
I am completly lost here...
